# Create page without menu item Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

Is there any way in Drupal 7 to creat simple page without any menu item from a custom module?
I want to create a thank-you page without any menu link.

Thanks 
Adam

Answer (score 1):

How much have you used drupal. For example do you know what templates are for?
If yes, go and make a new template for that page only, and then inside that template:

```
<?php print render($content); ?>
```

And wola. You might get something extra in that, but if you use devel, you can dig inside of that $content and then make it print only certain area of content ex. $content['2'] where ['2'] is sub array.
In my site i use adaptive themes, and i have page--node--64.tpl.php as and example!
Hope this helped.

And if you dont know how to do templates start from drupal's theming guide

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks fro your effort. I think I found a solution for this:
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,

I feel so sorry, but I miss the question. I would like to did this from a custom module and my problem was that I alwasy get a menu item but I fond this MENU_CALLBACK type wich was solved my problem.

Thanks again!

PS: I have corrected my question.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify your own answer for other people, using `hook_menu()` doesn't necesseraly create a menu item. It creates a page for a given path and it can create several things.

For example:

```
function hook_menu() {
  $items = array();
  // THIS will create a tab
  $items['user/%user/profile'] = array(
    'title' => 'Profile',
    'description' => 'My Profile',
    'page callback' => 'profile_user_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('view own profile'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
  // THIS will create a menu item
  $items['profile/%currentuser'] = array(
    'title' => 'Profile',
    'description' => 'My Profile',
    'page callback' => 'profile_user_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('view own profile'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'menu_name' => 'my_menu',
  );
  // And THIS will create nothing
  $items['user/add_user'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'add_new_user_form',
    'access arguments' => array('create new users'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```